# IllegalStateException Failed to load ApplicationContext custom handling

Tags: java, spring, исключения, rest, exception-handler

Возможно ли перехватить `IllegalStateException` в собственном обработчике исключений?Смысл в том, чтобы если в командной строке отсутствует имя файла, то обработчик перехватывал бы данную ошибку и формировал свой ответ клиенту. Попробовал методу добавить аннотацию `@ExceptionHandler(IllegalStateException.class)`, но не работает. Или требуется обработчик ставить на другой вид ошибок?

Comment: advice пробовали?

Comment: да, в advice у меня и находится метод c аннотацией @ExceptionHandler, просто при ошибке там выбрасывается 3 ошибки, в том числе и IllegalStateException